# Using gsub with a data frame getting an odd result, how you use gsub with a dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to use a gsub function on my data frame. In my data frame, I have phrases like "text.Democrat17_P" and many others with different numbers. My goal is to replace phrases like this with just, "DEM".

I first wanted to test the gsub function with only one row before I replace every value in the data frame. However, when I ran my script, gsub seemed to disassemble my data frame and list numbers out instead.

My result looked like this:

```html
[1] "c(14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 16)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [2] "c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 [3] "c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 [4] "c(2322, 2490, 2912, 3181, 3245, 2640, 3215, 4506, 3256, 2705, 2662, 5676, 7344, 2888, 2891, 4387, 9494, 2525, 3649, 1654, 2178, 2913, 2922, 3320, 7243, 5836, 6054, 6283, 4499, 5291, 4747, 2538, 5433, 5354, 5272, 4166, 3427, 5432, 4566, 5371, 5503, 4550, 1639, 2603, 3937, 2359, 1516, 1204, 826, 916, 1039, 1738, 2077, 874, 2495, 628, 582, 872, 2179, 682, 578, 476, 2207, 1178, 859, 1345, 1223, 2014, 438, 448, 1020, 879, 1117, 271, 210, 295, 233, 172, 77, 205, 3958)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 [5] "c(\"DEM\", \"text.Demminus14_P\", \"text.Demplus9_P\", \"text.Repminus11_O\", \"text.Repminus18_O\", \"text.Demminus12_P\", \"text.Repminus4_O\", \"text.Demminus12_P\", \"text.Repplus8_O\", \"text.Demminus4_P\", \"text.Demplus9_P\", \"text.Demminus20_P\", \"text.Repplus16_O\", \"text.Repminus10_O\", \"text.Repminus13_O\", \"text.Demplus18_P\", \"text.Repplus18_O\", \"text.Demplus1_P\", \"text.Repminus15_O\", \"text.Demminus11_P\", \"text.Repplus14_O\", \"text.Demminus8_P\", \"text.Repminus18_O\", \"text.Repminus13_O\", \"text.Demminus9_P\", \n\"text.Repminus13_O\", \"text.Repminus16_O\", \"text.Demminus9_P\", \"text.Repminus1_O\", \"text.Demplus15_P\", \"DEM\", \"text.Demminus1_P\", \"text.Repplus2_O\", \"text.Demminus18_P\", \"text.Repplus14_O\", \"text.Repminus20_O\", \"text.Repplus16_O\", \"text.Demplus2_P\", \"text.Repplus10_O\", \"text.Demminus18_P\", \"text.Repplus2_O\", \"text.Demminus15_P\", \"text.Repminus6_O\", \"text.Demminus19_P\", \"text.Repminus9_O\", \"text.Repplus15_O\", \"text.Repminus15_O\", \"text.Repminus8_O\", \"text.Repplus12_O\", \"text.Demminus19_P\", \n\"text.Repplus6_O\", \"text.Demplus13_P\", \"text.Demminus14_P\", \"text.Demminus5_P\", \"text.Demminus2_P\", \"text.Repplus1_O\", \"text.Repminus18_O\", \"text.Repplus14_O\", \"text.Demplus20_P\", \"text.Repplus6_O\", \"text.Repminus16_O\", \"text.Demminus19_P\", \"text.Demplus12_P\", \"text.Demminus12_P\", \"text.Demminus10_P\", \"text.Repplus5_O\", \"text.Demplus5_P\", \"text.Repplus17_O\", \"text.Repminus13_O\", \"text.Demplus3_P\", \"text.Demminus5_P\", \"text.Repminus10_O\", \"text.Repplus6_O\", \"text.Repplus16_O\", \"text.Repminus10_O\", \n\"text.Repplus1_O\", \"text.Demminus6_P\", \"text.Repplus5_O\", \"text.Demplus3_P\", \"text.Demplus3_P\", \"text.Repminus19_P\")"
```

Does anyone know why this happend and how I can get my result to look like a original data frame, with rows and columns.

This is the code that I am using:

```html
DDMB <- DDMBehavfin[1,]
DDMB
gsub (pattern= "text.Demminus17_P", replacement = "DEM", x= DDMB)
```

Could this have to do something with the datatype of the columns? What can I do to my gsub function so that I can gain a regular looking data frame instead of a messy result like this?

I first want to tackle why my result looks odd, before using gsub to replace all of the values.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You may need to `unlist`

Comment: Would I need to apply that to all my columns before I run gsub?  I tried it like this but it didnt change anything:                            
unlist(gsub (pattern= "text.Demminus17_P", replacement = "DEM", x= DDMB)
)

Comment: If you need to apply gsub on all columns, then loop over the columns with `DDMBehavfin[] <- lapply(DDMBehavfin, gsub, pattern= "text.Demminus17_P", replacement = "DEM")`

Comment: Assuming you want to preserve it as a `data.frame`, use @akrun's last comment, `lapply(..., gsub, ...)`.

Comment: @akrun Sorry I am a bit conufued, all of the columns dont have "text.Demminus17_P". Also I am only just learning about gsub, so I'd rather try and understand why my output looks weird first.

Comment: the issue is that you applied on a `data.frame` instead of a vector and `gsub` expects a vector input

Comment: or you can vectorise, rather than use `lapply`, by using `DDMB[] = gsub("text.Demminus17_P", "DEM", unlist(DDMB))`

Comment: @dww, this works, but does DDMB[] have to match unlist (DDMB)? I tried making another vector  but it showed up as an error.

Comment: yes - the replacement values need to be the same length as the location yo insert into.  As others noted, a reproducible example would allow us to give more specific answers